# Передача заголовков в теге audio angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Здраствуйте. У меня есть spring boot rest сервер, из которого я получаю нужный аудио файл.
Я использую jwt аутентификацию, поэтому нужно передавать на каждый запрос jwt токен.

Как можно передать заголовки? Использование interceptor не помогло т.к. он перехватывает запросы HttpClient (если ошибаюсь исправте)

Вот тег audio:

```
<audio controls="">
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/api/song/cf21bb2b-42cc-4da1-bd5e-f4da655626b5.mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Кидаете запрос на свой бек, он уже спрашивает сам файл у нужного сервера, и возвращает его на бек, а тот, в свою очередь, на фронт. html ещё не научился кидаться заголовками. Опишите подробней что и как вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Для того, чтобы отослать запрос на бек нужно вместе с запросом отослать bearer токен. В противном случае, мы получим 403. Проблема в том, что из html токен отослать не получится. Возможно ли передать в src какую-нибудь функцию, которая возвращает файл, который мы сможем воспроизвести?

Comment: Вам ничто не мешает получать файл тем же httpclient на ngoninit и подставлять ссылку в теги